# Why is this panic example below a type error in golang?

Tags: go, types

Why is this panicf-sprintf causing a ***type*** error in Golang 1.11? Go doesn't explain the reason, even if it says this is a common mistake.

https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#vet

`go vet` is now enforced during the build.

```
func panicf(s string, i ...interface{}) { panic(fmt.Sprintf(s, i)) }
```

The test is returning

```
missing ... in args forwarded to printf-like function
```

`vet` describes this as

```
func (*ptrStringer) BadWrap(x int, args ...interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprint(args) // ERROR "missing ... in args forwarded to print-like function"
}

func (*ptrStringer) BadWrapf(x int, format string, args ...interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(format, args) // ERROR "missing ... in args forwarded to printf-like function"
```

Please help explain `...` in ***golang*** in this context.

Here is a functional playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DijjanQNkxK

Comment: Take a look at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters and https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`panicf()` accepts `i` as a variadic, the same as `fmt.Sprintf()`. Therefore you have to tell the compiler that you want each value of `i` to be sent to `fmt.Sprintf()` instead of sending the entire thing as a slice.

So change the code to:

```
func panicf(s string, i ...interface{}) { panic(fmt.Sprintf(s, i...)) }
```